# how to write this query? (none existing item)

Tags: mysql

this is my countries table:

```
id | name
```

this is my languages table:

```
id | name
```

this is the countryLanguages table joining them:

```
id | country_id | language_id
```

now i want to write a query that make such selection

```
language_id | language_name
```

where language does not exist in countryLanguages table for country id=3.

example:

```
countries:
1 | US
2 | UK
3 | CHINA

languages:
1 | chinese
2 | spanish
3 | english

countryLanguages:
1 | 1 | 3
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 2 | 3
4 | 3 | 1
```

and it should be returned:

```
2 | spanish
3 | english
```

since spanish and english are not spoken in china.

Comment: You are saying language does not exist in `countryLanguages` table for country id=3 and yet you example has `language_id` for country_id=3.  Also your `and it should be returned:` in your example is not clear.  What should return?  Something that you've tried for this would be helpful!

Comment: in this example language english (id=2) and spanish (id=3) do not exist for chinese language in the same rows of countryLanguges table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a sub query as followed:

```
# this is the outer select for every language not in the list returned from the inner query
SELECT * FROM languages WHERE languages.id NOT IN (
   # this is the inner select for every language spoken in country 3
   SELECT
        languages.id
   FROM 
        countries, countryLanguages, languages
   WHERE
        countries.id = countryLanguages.country_id AND
        languages.id = countryLanguages.language_id AND
        countries.id = 3
 );
```

Please note that sub queries are not always the fastest way to do something and that you can usually come up with a cleaver join instead, but this should do what you are looking for.

Comment: do you know how to do that with joining?

Comment: I'd have to think more about it, so that would have to wait until after work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from languages where id not in (select language_id from countryLanguages where country_id=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cl.language_id,
  l.name


FROM languages AS l

JOIN countryLanguages AS cl
  ON cl.language_id = l.id

JOIN countries AS c
  ON c.id = cl.country_id
 AND c.name != 'CHINA'
```

You could also use `AND c.id != 3`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/082e9/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cl.language_id, l.name
FROM languages AS l
JOIN countryLanguages AS cl ON cl.language_id = l.id
WHERE cl.country_id != 3
```